# Can I get HSS/TTL with a Godox AD360 with a Sony A7r II?

Tags: sony, off-camera-flash, godox

I have a Godox AD360 (manual) and a Sony A7r II. If I get an X1T-S transmitter can I achieve HSS? TTL? What receiver do I need?

Answer (score 1):

You *can* get remote power control and HSS if you use an XTR-16 receiver (vs. the older FTR-16) with your AD360, but the AD360 is manual only, so there is no way to get TTL, unless you use the TTL-capable AD360 II (which has an X1 receiver built-in).

See: [Flash Havoc's guide to the Godox 2.4GHz system](http://flashhavoc.com/godox-flash-system-overview/).